# Pass the key to predicate as parameter in predicateWithFormat

Tags: ios, cocoa, nspredicate

This may sounds silly, but here is the data to predicate:

```
@interface Person

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *phone;
@property NSString *address;

@end
```

I got an NSPredicate that will search through Person Array, search by Name. Normally, I will use it like

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
```

But how can I use the key (name) as a parameter? Like

```
NSString *key = @"name";
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[c] %@", key, searchText];
```

The predicate1 works fine, but the predicate2 doesn't. The different of those 2 when I debug with lldb:

```
po [predicate1 predicateFormat]
name CONTAINS[c] "Eddie"

po [predicate2 predicateFormat]
"name" CONTAINS[c] "Eddie"
```

Question is: Can I make the predicate2 work? I want to pass the key to search (name) as a parameter... If I can, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

> When string variables are substituted into a format string using `%@` , they are surrounded by quotation marks. If you want to specify a dynamic property name, use `%K` in the format string

So your predicate should be

```
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", key, searchText];
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I use it like @"@K.@K contains[c] %@", parentKey, mainKey, searchText ?

Comment: @Eddie, if you think that this answer solves your issue described in your question, please, accept it, and if you have any more questions, you have to include those in your question by editing, or ask another ones. Good Luck!

Comment: @Eddie not sure, but it looks reasonable and it's worth a shot. Otherwise just concat the keys before passing them as a parameter to the format string.

Comment: They said I can't accept an answer in 8mins, then I forget about it =] sorry