# Can I use `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables` or something similar for the key instead of the value?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

Once I asked for how to pass 1 keywords to multiple keys and got this answer: [Use 1 search value for multiple keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31129169/1696598). And then, I asked for how to pass the key as param: [Pass the key as param in NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673885/1696598)

So now, I'm curious if I can do the vice-versa: Can I pass multiple keys as param with 1 (or maybe many) search words? If yes, then how would it look like?

Some code for you guys to edit.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(($key = 'value1') 
                           @" OR ($key = 'value2')) "
                           @" AND ($key != '0') "]; 

predicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"key": @"myProperty"}];
```

Note that in the predicate, there's a (AND !=) so I won't be able to use the `IN predicate`:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myProperty IN %@", 
                                 @[@"value1", @"value2", @"value3"]];`

Those are just some sample code so please don't try to fix the predicate but keep your eyes on the question: `substituteVariables` with the variables is the Key to filter.

Comment: Did you try and did it work?

Comment: It doesn't. I used normal predicate (`id = 1 OR id = 2`) and print it out in lldb and it show: `id == 1 OR id == 2`. However, when use predicate with the sample, it show: `"id" == 1 OR "id" ==2` and doesn't filter correct data. It seems `subtitutionVariables` replace the placeholder with a string, not as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key must be a keypath expression:

```
[predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"key": [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"myProperty"]}]
```

will result in predicate

```
(myProperty == "value1" OR myProperty == "value2") AND myProperty != "0"
```